# Attack vectors for server to server using untrusted HTTPS certificates?

Tags: tls, rest

I have noticed a large amount of server-side HTTP client libraries accept untrusted TLS communication by default. For example, from the documentation for node's [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

> `strictSSL` - If true, requires SSL certificates be valid.

This is `false` unless set, in other words, untrusted SSL certs are accepted by default. I'm not specifically picking on request, it's by no means alone when it comes to this behaviour.

**What are obvious attack vectors for server-to-server communication (typically a REST API) using untrusted SSL certs?**

Eg, DNS cache poisoning could be used to replace the real endpoint with an attacker's replacement that uses a self-signed cert.

Are there others?

Comment: I've asked for this to be closed - per discussion with @steffanulrich below, the question is too broad. I have now re-asked the question more specifically in a separate thread.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP asked for it to be closed

Answer (score 1):

When a client doesn't check the SSL certificate of the server that it is connecting to, this opens the door for a Man In the Middle (MITM) attack.  As the name implies, this type of attack is pulled off by someone between the client and the server.  In practice, there are a number of scenarios where this can take place.  See [How does a Man In the Middle attack happen in reality](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111824/how-does-a-man-in-the-middle-attack-happen-in-reality) for more info.

Comment: Sure: the fake wifi hotspot is obvious. But that's a client-specific attack. I'm asking for server-to-server MITM attack vectors.

Comment: @mikemaccana: in server-to-server scenarios one of the physical servers is the logical client to the other one (client: initiate connection, server: accept connection). So MITM still applies here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm asking about specific MITM attacks - that's why I mention one example of a MITM attack in the question. However I things like a rogue WiFi access point is an unlikely route of attack, hence asking this question.

Comment: @mikemaccana: ARP spoofing and most of the typical MITM attacks apply to any computer-to-computer scenarios including server to server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich For an ARP spoofing attack you'd generally have to compromise a host in the same datacenter as the server, right? I was looking for commonly exploited server-based MITM attacks rather than a general 'all MITM attacks apply' answer because clearly some, like wireless networks or VLANS shared with unknown parties are less likely to happen in server environments. I thought that was evident from the question but perhaps not, maybe I should just delete the question and be more specific.

Comment: @mikemaccana: It would be enough to rent a server in the same datacenter, no need to hijack it. But yes, maybe it is better to make your question more specific to the network setup you have actually in mind.